# How to generate WEP keys from a passphrase

Tags: command-line, security, passphrase

I have a passphrase and I want to generate a WEP keys from it.

Are there a linux command for that?

Comment: Please don't use WEP. It's not secure *at all*.

Comment: @Oli I know that. the goal is not to use WEP. the goal is to developp an inetrface for user which can use it to generate a WEP key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [WepPassphrase](http://www.sthu.org/code/weppassphrase.html). I have not used it myself, but it looks like what you need. Source code is provided, so you can amend it as needed.

But @Oli is right: You might as well use nothing as use WEP.